# aborting ``Object.wait`` without the object

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait, deadlock

Let's say I have a structure that guards access eventually by

```
while(must_wait){

    ...

    if(must_wait){
        try {
            synchronized(target){
                target.wait();
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

But let's also assume I have a deadlock checker somewhere that is telling me I need to abort my current attempt at acquiring the lock.

```
while(must_wait && not_aborted){

    ...

    if(must_wait){
        try {
            synchronized(target){
                target.wait();
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    not_aborted = ...
}
```

CAN I wake up the current thread if the deadlock checker does not have access to `target`, or do I need to check every so often, i.e.

```
while(must_wait && not_aborted){

    ...

    if(must_wait){
        try {
            synchronized(target){
                target.wait(TIMEOUT);
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    not_aborted = ...
}
```

?

(Yes, I do know about `LockSupport.park/unpark`, but the problem with that is that then I'd need to hand a reference to the current thread to the target, and I do want to avoid that.)

Comment: When that thread is blocking it already has the lock so you can't, "abort my current attempt at acquiring the lock" In general parking waiting for a thread to complete is a terrible place to hold a lock. I would refactor my code to ensure I hold locks for as little time as possible.

Comment: @JimW ``target`` is not the data we're acquiring the lock for, but a queue node keeping track of conditions. Still, how would your refactor above snippet?